# How do I approach solving this first order nonlinear equation : $ y' = A (y_0 - y) -B f(x) y $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an analytical solution for any given f(x) function ?

I am clueless on how to approach this analytically, any leads are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to rearrange the proposed ODE as follows?

$$y' + (Bf(x) + a)y = Ay_{0}$$

Comment: Yes. But the issue I have is how to deal with f(x) here

Comment: As the question is stated, you can apply the integrating factor method considering a generic function $f(x)$. This is as far as one can go here unless $f$ is specified.